# PHP Sorting the list of directories relative to the path (?)

Tags: php, file, sorting

I have a problem and I do not know how to describe it, so I will go straight to the code:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/\.(html|php|phtml|storage|tmp|txt|ini)*$/i');

foreach($files as $file){
    echo $file->getRealpath();
}
```

**He receives something like that:**

C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\aa.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\cc.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\ccc.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\file.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\test.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\test2.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\file.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\sth.txt

**I would like to receive something like this:**

C:\xampp\htdocs\file.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\sth.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\aa.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\cc.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\ccc.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\file.txt
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\test.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\test\test2.php

**How can I receive such a thing? Thank you in advance for every answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly improved version from @Ghost to care for sorting within the substructures:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/\.(html|php|phtml|storage|tmp|txt|ini)*$/i');
$data = array();
foreach($iterator as $file) {
    $depth = $files->getDepth(); // get depth
    $data[$depth][] = $file->getRealpath(); // push depth inside another dimension with the file
}

// this is necessary that items within the depth are sorted correctly, first sort by key (the depth) than sort by name
ksort($data);
foreach ($data as $depthArray){
    sort($depthArray);
}

$data = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data); // flatten all items
// use data
```

This will still have problems when directories contain a lot of subdirectories. This example:

```
a\b.html
downtheway\a.html
a\a.html
a\sub1\c.sorted
```

would be solted like this:

```
a\b.html
a\a.html
downtheway\a.html // wrong
a\sub1\c.html
```

because the algorithm only takes the depth into account and

```
a\sub1\c.html
```

is deeper than

```
downtheway\a.html
```

@Trawlr: Is this correct for your use case or should be sorted like this:

```
a\b.html
a\a.html
a\sub1\c.html
downtheway\a.html
```

---

Old Answer was not exactly what OP asked.

Use just the regular `sort` for arrays. This should work without problem.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/\.(html|php|phtml|storage|tmp|txt|ini)*$/i');

$array = array();
foreach($files as $file){
    $array[] = $file->getRealpath();
}
sort($array, SORT_STRING);
//output array
```

You could also combine `SORT_STRING` with `SORT_FLAG_CASE` to ignore the case of the string. Would look like this:

```
sort($array, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE );
```

Comment: it does not work, but the usort function is closer to solving my problem, but thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sort them by depth of the file, you can utilize `->getDepth` method to get the current depth, and assign them to each group for the files. Group them first, at the end just merge them and you'll all have them lined up.

Here's the idea:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/\.(html|php|phtml|storage|tmp|txt|ini)*$/i');
$data = array();
foreach($iterator as $file) {
    $depth = $files->getDepth(); // get depth
    $data[$depth][] = $file->getRealpath(); // push depth inside another dimension with the file
}

$data = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data); // flatten all items
```